# Issues with Angular/Firebase data

Tags: angular, database, firebase

I'm sort of new to Angular and I'm working on a small project for an internship. I created the front-end and sending data into the database, but now I'm having issues with retrieving the data.
I Googled some stuff and created an async function that's supposed to return the data, but when I do it's in a Zone Aware Promise format in the console, or when I use the .then() function, I can only console log the array of data, but cannot return it or pass it to a global variable. Here's the code from the component:

```
import {getDatabase, ref} from "firebase/database";
import {get} from "@angular/fire/database";

public async getVehicles() {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const snapshot = await get(ref(db, 'vehicles'));
    return snapshot.val();
  }
```

and when I do this:

```
this.getVehicles().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I get the array of data as I want it in the console. How can I get the data itself inside an outside variable, so I can use it and manipulate it as a regular array?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this today with the help of my friend. Here's the code for anyone facing a similar issue, hope it helps.

```java
public async getVehicles() {
    const db = getDatabase();
    // I made a loading component appear while the data is being fetched.
    this.showLoading = true;
    const snapshot = await get(ref(db, 'vehicles'));
    // placed the promise value into a temporary object, for some reason the data is stored as an object where attributes are the list values I'm trying to get.
    let temp = snapshot.val();
    this.list = Object.keys(temp).map(index => {
      return temp[index];
    });
    // took every element of the returned object and individually placed them into the main list
    this.showLoading= false;
    return snapshot.val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. add a class field called list with `let list : any`
2. on anytime you want to get the data use:

```js
this.getVehicles().then(data => {
    this.list = data;
});
```

Or if you are on an async function you can use this:

```js
this.list = await this.getVehicles();
```

Comment: When I create the list variable and use the function you mentioned, I get undefined in the console.

Comment: @tare22 can you share the full code where it logs undefined

Comment: I actually managed to fix this today, I will post the final code in an answer so others can see it if they run into the same issue.